# Problem receiving an array as pointer parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, c++98

Hi I have a trouble trying to manage a the following array.
I have initialized this pointer `int* coordenadasFicha = new int[2];` and I want to asign the two `int` asking the user for the numbers.
The trouble appears when I call `pedirCoordenadasFicha(coordenadasFicha);` Clion recomends me cast `coordenadasFicha` to `int**` but I need to use it as a simple pointer. pedirCoordenadasFicha() basically does this:

```
void pedirCoordenadasFicha(int* coordenadasFicha[2]){
    std::cin >> *coordenadasFicha[0];
    std::cin >> *coordenadasFicha[1];}
```

All help is welcome

Comment: Please include a [mre] and the exact problem you are experiencing (don't just call it "trouble").  Relevant code is missing from this question, but you seem to be mixing up `int*` and `int[2]` and `int*[2]`

Comment: `Clion recomends me cast coordenadasFicha to int**` This seems like a bad recommendation. Are you sure it recommends that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `int*` (a pointer-to-int) and an `int*[]` (an array of pointer-to-int) are two different things.  And actually, in a function parameter, `int* coordenadasFicha[2]` is actually passed as `int**` (pointer to pointer-to-int), because an array *decays* into a pointer to its 1st element.

In your case, you are creating `coordenadasFicha` as an dynamic array of `int`s, but your function is expecting an array of `int*` pointers instead.

So, to do what you are attempting, you would need to do either this:

```cpp
void pedirCoordenadasFicha(int* coordenadasFicha){
    std::cin >> coordenadasFicha[0];
    std::cin >> coordenadasFicha[1];
}

int* coordenadasFicha = new int[2];
pedirCoordenadasFicha(coordenadasFicha);
...
delete[] coordenadasFicha;
```

Or this:

```cpp
void pedirCoordenadasFicha(int* coordenadasFicha[2]){
    std::cin >> *coordenadasFicha[0];
    std::cin >> *coordenadasFicha[1];
}

int** coordenadasFicha = new int*[2];
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    coordenadasFicha[i] = new int;
}
pedirCoordenadasFicha(coordenadasFicha);
...
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    delete coordenadasFicha;
}
delete[] coordenadasFicha;
```

Or, just get rid of `new` altogether, and pass the array by reference:

```cpp
void pedirCoordenadasFicha(int (&coordenadasFicha)[2]){
    std::cin >> coordenadasFicha[0];
    std::cin >> coordenadasFicha[1];
}

int coordenadasFicha[2];
pedirCoordenadasFicha(coordenadasFicha);
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was using an array of pointer-to-int instead of a pointer-to-int

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use it as a simple pointer.

`int* coordenadasFicha[2]` is not a "simple pointer", if by simple pointer you mean `int*`. In any other context, `coordenadasFicha` would be an array of pointers, but function parameters aren't arrays in C++; the parameter is adjusted to be a pointer to element of such array. The element of the array is `int*` and a pointer to `int*` is `int**`. Hence the type of `coordenadasFicha` is `int**` (after adjustment).

If you want a parameter to have the type `int*`, then you must declare the parameter to have the type `int*` and not some other type. Example:

```
void
pedirCoordenadasFicha(int* coordenadasFicha)
{
    std::cin >> coordenadasFicha[0];
    std::cin >> coordenadasFicha[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!